# Say how to create a menu that doesn't use recursion in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, recursion, menu

I want to create a select menu like this but without the use of recursion:

```
echo "Choose your option:"
echo "1. Visulizzazione Processi"
echo "2. Filtra Processi"
echo "3. Termina Processi"
echo "4. Modifica Priorità Processi"
echo "5. Esci dal Programma"
```

Comment: Looked at [select](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_06.html)? 
http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/
http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion
Please elaborate, and show us what you have *tried*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

ENTRY1="Visulizzazione Processi"
ENTRY2="Filtra Processi"
ENTRY3="Termina Processi"
ENTRY4="Modifica Priorità Processi"
ENTRY5="Esci dal Programma"

Menu=("$ENTRY1" "$ENTRY2" "$ENTRY3" "$ENTRY4" "$ENTRY5")

select your_change in "${Menu[@]}"; do
    case "$your_change" in
       $ENTRY1) echo "$ENTRY1" ;;
       $ENTRY2) echo "$ENTRY2" ;;
       $ENTRY3) echo "$ENTRY3" ;;
       $ENTRY4) echo "$ENTRY4" ;;
       $ENTRY5) exit
    esac
done
```